# gmail-api marking as "read"

Tags: android, gmail-api

Using gmail-api I am trying to mak a message as "read" as below but it s not working.

```
 ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest()
            .setRemoveLabelIds(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("UNREAD")));
    com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message message = null;
    try {
        message = mService.users().messages().modify(acct.sEmail, gmsailID, mods).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception/error you're getting?  That code doesn't seem that unreasonable...

Comment: I dont see any exception

Comment: Can you please provide full response then?  What's the problem?

Comment: I printed the message returned to answer you and saw "labelIds" : [ "INBOX", "IMPORTANT", "CATEGORY_PERSONAL" ], which means the message was marked as unread . So further investigating got the issue that i was checking isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN) after converting to mimmessage. This will not work. What i see is that we need to check "UNREAD" label is present or not to see if read or unread. Couldnt find any other way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for setRemoveLabelIds()   is not the Label String but the Label ID. 
So get the label ID from the code below and use that in your function

```
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(userId).execute();
    for (Label label : listResponse.getLabels()) {
        Label countLabel = service.users().labels().get(userId, label.getId()).execute();
        if (countLabel.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("UNREAD"))
            unreadId = countLabel.getId();
    }
    List<String> add = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> remove = new ArrayList<String>();
    remove.add(unreadId);
    modifyMessage(service, userId, message.getId(), add, remove);


public static void modifyMessage(Gmail service, String userId, String messageId,
                                 List<String> labelsToAdd, List<String> labelsToRemove) throws IOException {
    ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest().setAddLabelIds(labelsToAdd)
            .setRemoveLabelIds(labelsToRemove);
    Message message = service.users().messages().modify(userId, messageId, mods).execute();
}
```

Comment: For system labels like UNREAD the name and ID are the same:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels
though it doesn't really make it clear in those docs, that's how it works.  Can be easily seen from API explorer.

Comment: Yes the name and id are same. I tried with ID and it didnt work . Do i have to add some other labels also .

Comment: @preetha, please try with my updated code and if that still doesn't work please post your entire code, we'll see what might be going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that I use (after getting messageId with ListMessagesResponse):

```
public void modifyMessage(String userId, String messageId) throws IOException {
        List<String> lblIDRemove=new ArrayList<String>();
        lblIDRemove.add("UNREAD");
        ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest()
                .setAddLabelIds(null)
                .setRemoveLabelIds(lblIDRemove);
        Message message = mService.users().messages().modify(userId, messageId, mods).execute();
    }
```